# If I want to spoof my wireless router's MAC address for privacy reasons, how should I pick one?

Tags: mac-address

Like the title says: how do I decide which "random" MAC address to assign to a machine in order to hide the real one?

Just entering a random one doesn't feel very... scientific.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of "privacy" are we talking about here? MAC addresses are only visible on the local network, not on the Internet, so changing your MAC doesn't really give you any privacy benefit. On the local network changing your MAC will make it harder to link your traffic to your physical device (so if you do something malicious, it'll be harder for the local network admin to prove that the malicious traffic came from your device), but that's about it - and even then, other cues will probably give you away.

Comment: I don't care about hiding it inside the LAN. I'm actually taking about the wireless router's MAC. Can't ISPs for example read MAC addresses and trace traffic for example?

Comment: I always thought MAC addresses **were** random anyway - like a UUID, chances of any 2 coming up with the same random set of characters is too small to even bother about.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but aren't they unique and traceable to a hardware device?